# jQuery Carousel Stuck (Twitter Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've implemented Twitter Bootstrap's Carousel jQuery plugin here:
http://zarin.me/circlefive/dashboard.html (see the responses tab)

The carousel usually functions, but occasionally gets stuck. It especially happens when you interact with the other tabs and then using the responses tab. I think it has to do with the tabs..

Does anyone know why the carousel is getting stuck?

Thanks!

Comment: Related: [issue 1887](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1887), [issue 2196](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/2196), [question: how to combine tabs and carousel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327796/how-to-combine-tabs-and-carousel-in-‌​twitter-bootstrap/12332045)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is along the lines of what @Francesco Frassinelli pointed out in the comment, namely that when the carousel is using CSS3 transitions (basically any browser but IE), if a carousel is hidden when a transition ends, the `$.support.transition.end` event is never fired.  This will cause the carousel to get suspended in the **sliding** state and short-circuit all it's functionality.

In [Issue #1887](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/1887) **@fat** threw in his suggestion for preventing it from getting stuck in the first place:

> "You'll need to pause the slide show and resume it before/after toggling the display."

I also suggested a workaround for when using a carousel in a modal in [Issue #3351](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3351#issuecomment-7118931), which could easily be adapted for your use case:

```
$('a[href="#responses-1"]').on('shown', function () {
    var $carousel = $('.carousel');

    if ($carousel.data('carousel') && $carousel.data('carousel').sliding) {
      $carousel.find('.active').trigger($.support.transition.end);
    }
});
```

This basically just unlocks the carousel when it becomes visible if it happens to be suspended.

Since this poor behavior occurs across many differently scenarios, I made a suggestion in [Issue #3351](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/3351) as to the feasibility of a potential permanent solution which could be integrated directly into the **bootstrap-carousel.js** plugin code. If anyone thinks that is a good idea, or have other ideas as to how to accomplish it, that issue is still open, so feedback is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the behaviour of the carousel in chrome you can the carousel if still running when you change tab.

And because the carousel is not in the active tab a `display: none;` is applied to parent div of the carousel. This may be the cause of your problem. (you end up like the screenshot)

I think it can be fixed by triggering `.carousel('pause')` when clicking on the 3 first tab and `.carousel('cycle')` on the last tab before showing the content related to the tab.

[image: carousel stuck]